# Activating segues out side of the UIViewController in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8 with swift 3

I have created a segue in the mainStoryboard, going from a tableview to another view controller. I called this segue `segue`. What I mean by segue is the links between the different view, such as a table view and a standard view. Like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoRMzCc7yjo, at about the 12 minute and 30 second mark.

You can then activate the segue (Move between the views) using:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

I'm trying to create a function so I can use this (`performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)`) from outside of a  `UIViewController` class. The function looks something like this:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {
    public func myFunction() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then when I try using `myFunction` outside of the `UIViewController` it does not work, coming up with the error

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'myFunction'".

I realise that this is because `myFunction` is not a global function, it is declared within The viewController class.

I need to be able to activate the segue outside of the viewController class, like in the code below:

```
struct QuestionAnswerer {

    func responseTo() {

        //This makes all the caracters lower cased.
        let lowerQuestion = question.lowercased()

        if lowerQuestion.range(of: "Photos") != nil {
            myFunction()
        } else {
            myOtherFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Answers are greatly appreciated

Comment: where are you using `myFunction()` ? please show the code

Comment: So if you already know your function is not accessible from some object, why not make it accessible? Right now it sounds like your issue is totally different than what you think it is. Take things one step at a time - for instance, if in your rather odd setup, can `myFunction` be executed like you want? If not, then why do you think - based on your title - that this has anything to do with segues?

Comment: How do you make it accessible? @dfd

Comment: That depends on much - things you haven't shown in your question. For starters, like @3stud1ant3 asked, *where* are you calling this code? How is `viewController` being instantiated? Where is `"segue"` defined? I guess congrats on limiting your question to something minimal, but this isn't something anyone can answer because you went *too* minimal! :-)

Comment: @dfd I have tried to add some more information. hopefully this clarifies the question.

Comment: It helps - some. *"It looks something like this..."* At this point to me it looks like some of your issue (maybe not all) has nothing to do with a segue but instead what is called "variable scope". I'd like to rule that out. Again, can you try to give full context of how `myFunction` from `viewController` is being called from someplace else? I'm really making sure *you* are on the right track - something to do with calling "segue" from another place. But you first need to rule out more basic things.

Comment: @dfd My problem is to do with the scope of the function myFunction. I have added more details above to help clarify the question.

Comment: @dfd I am creating a chat bot and, when it finds a certain key word, I want it to open up another view where the user enters some information then returns to the original view.

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of hard to tell what you want, since I think you already have it.

One of the best ways for performing a function is exactly what you have above. You would simply use the following:

```
struct GlobalFunctions {
    static func myFunction() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And then to call it, you would use:

```
GlobalFunctions.myFunction()
```

EDIT:
I think the problem is that a segue is designed to go from A to B. If you're in C and you try to go from A, you would get an error. Here's a new idea. From each view controller, connect a segue to the target controller (B). Call them 'segueFromA', 'segueFromC', etc.
Then change the code to the following:

```
struct GlobalFunctions {
    static func myFunction(from: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue\(from)", sender: self)
    }
}
```

If you're calling it from view controller A, you would use:

```
GlobalFunctions.myFunction(from: "A")
```

If calling from view controller C, you would use:

```
GlobalFunctions.myFunction(from: "C")
```

Etc. I hope you get the idea :D

Comment: When I put this in my view controller I get the error: /Users/macbookair/Documents/Swift/ChatBot/encryptionContrller.swift:15:13: Instance member 'performSegue' cannot be used on type 'UIViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?